# Preserve index and column order when combining DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have the following DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1_column_array = [['foo', 'bar'],
          ['A', 'B']]
df1_column_tuple = list(zip(*df1_column_array))    
df1_column_header = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df1_column_tuple)

df1_index_array = [['one','two'],
          ['0', '1']]
df1_index_tuple = list(zip(*df1_index_array))  
df1_index_header = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df1_index_tuple)


df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,2), columns = df1_column_header, index = df1_index_header)
print(df1)
            foo       bar
              A         B
one 1  0.755296  0.101329
two 2  0.925653  0.587948

df2_column_array = [['alpha', 'beta'],
          ['C', 'D']]
df2_column_tuple = list(zip(*df2_column_array))    
df2_column_header = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df2_column_tuple)

df2_index_array = [['three', 'four'],
          ['3', '4']]
df2_index_tuple = list(zip(*df2_index_array))  
df2_index_header = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df2_index_tuple)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,2), columns = df2_column_header, index = df2_index_header)
print(df2)
            alpha      beta
                C         D
three 3  0.751013  0.957824
four  4  0.879353  0.045079
```

I would like to combine these DataFrames to produce:

```
              foo       bar     alpha      beta
                A         B         C         D
one   1  0.755296  0.101329       NaN       NaN
two   2  0.925653  0.587948       NaN       NaN
three 3       NaN       NaN  0.751013  0.957824
four  4       NaN       NaN  0.879353  0.045079
```

When I try concat, the order of the indices are preserved, but not of the columns:

```
df_joined = pd.concat([df1,df2])
print(df_joined)
            alpha       bar      beta       foo
                C         B         D         A
one   1       NaN  0.101329       NaN  0.755296
two   2       NaN  0.587948       NaN  0.925653
three 3  0.751013       NaN  0.957824       NaN
four  4  0.879353       NaN  0.045079       NaN
```

When I try join, the order of the columns are preserved, but not of the indices:

```
df_joined = df1.join(df2, how = 'outer')
print(df_joined)
              foo       bar     alpha      beta
                A         B         C         D
four  4       NaN       NaN  0.879353  0.045079
one   1  0.755296  0.101329       NaN       NaN
three 3       NaN       NaN  0.751013  0.957824
two   2  0.925653  0.587948       NaN       NaN
```

How can I preserve the order of both columns and indices when combining DataFrames?

Edit 1:
Please note: this is sample data. My real world data does not have convenient labels (e.g. 1,2,3,4) to sort on.

Edit 2:
When applying the proposes solution to my real world data, I get the following error:

```
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hack` - first concat and get `Multiindex` and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) output of second `concat`:

```
idx = pd.concat([df1,df2]).index
df_joined = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).reindex(idx)
print (df_joined)
              foo       bar     alpha      beta
                A         B         C         D
one   0  0.269298  0.819375       NaN       NaN
two   1  0.574702  0.798920       NaN       NaN
three 3       NaN       NaN  0.436893  0.822041
four  4       NaN       NaN  0.757332  0.271900
```

Faster solution with creating `DataFrames` with `Multiindexes`, concat it and get `index`:

```
idx = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df1.index, index=df1.index),
                 pd.DataFrame(df2.index, index=df2.index)]).index
df_joined = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).reindex(idx)
print (df_joined)
              foo       bar     alpha      beta
                A         B         C         D
one   0  0.007644  0.341335       NaN       NaN
two   1  0.332005  0.449688       NaN       NaN
three 3       NaN       NaN  0.281876  0.883299
four  4       NaN       NaN  0.880252  0.061797
```

EDIT1:

Problem of solution before is `reindex` hates duplicates.
So if `Multiindex` in columns is not duplicated, you can use:

```
print(df1)
            foo       bar
              A         B
one 0  0.384705  0.932928
    0  0.539197  0.519196

print(df2)
            alpha      beta
                C         D
three 3  0.957530  0.985926
four  4  0.479828  0.350042

cols = df1.join(df2, how = 'outer').columns
df_joined = pd.concat([df1,df2]).reindex(columns=cols)
print (df_joined)
              foo       bar     alpha      beta
                A         B         C         D
one   0  0.384705  0.932928       NaN       NaN
      0  0.539197  0.519196       NaN       NaN
three 3       NaN       NaN  0.957530  0.985926
four  4       NaN       NaN  0.479828  0.350042
```

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer: This is sample data, my real world data does not have convenient labels (e.g. 1,2,3,4) to sort on.

Comment: Thank you for accepting! I add second faster solution, please check if it works nice with real data. Nice day!

Comment: Apologies, when applying this to my real world data, I get the following error:  Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! Thoughts?

Comment: Please test another solution, if it doesnt work, please add some sample for better testing.

Comment: Alas, it does not work. I'll try to come up with an example which shows the same behavior

Comment: Maybe if use `df1_index_array = [['one','one'],
          ['0', '0']]`, then it is duplicates index.

Comment: I add another solution, please check it.

Comment: That works! Thank you so much for sticking with me here. I don't know about you, but I feel pandas can be quite unintuitive sometimes with its unexpected behavior and gotchas...

Comment: Ya, duplicates complicated works, super it works. Nice day. And thank for accepting.